# Android JSON parsing from google-shopping-api error

Tags: android, json, google-shopping-api

I decided I wanted to try using the Google shopping API out last week, but I had no idea how to parse JCON objects.

After much searching here I was able to get the product information for an item! However, I cannot narrow down to just a string in the product. So for example I want to just get the title of a product.

I have the following:

jsonString:

```
{
 "kind": "shopping#products",
 "etag": "\"GKsxsRlaBDslDpMe-MT1O7wqUDE/dMvQ5Pu2C806fWZJbNJ0GjdesJs\"",
 "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=US&restrictBy=gtin:051500240908&startIndex=1&maxResults=25",
 "totalItems": 3,
 "startIndex": 1,
 "itemsPerPage": 25,
 "currentItemCount": 3,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "shopping#product",
   "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/7585088/9884865157760252836",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/7585088/gid/9884865157760252836",
   "product": {
    "googleId": "9884865157760252836",
    "author": {
     "name": "Southeastern Delivery",
     "accountId": "7585088"
    },
    "creationTime": "2011-07-25T00:15:58.000Z",
    "modificationTime": "2012-02-11T09:29:00.000Z",
    "country": "US",
    "language": "en",
    "title": "Jif Peanut Butter, Creamy",
    "description": "Jif Creamy Peanut Butter. Fresh Roasted Peanut Taste. Look for the flavor seal. Contains no preservatives. No refrigeration required.",
    "link": "http://www.southeasterndelivery.com/Jif_Peanut_Butter_00051500240908/",
    "brand": "Jif Peanut Butter",
    "condition": "new",
    "gtin": "00051500240908",
    "gtins": [
     "00051500240908"
    ],
    "inventories": [
     {
      "channel": "online",
      "availability": "inStock",
      "price": 15.64,
      "shipping": 1.56,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ],
    "images": [
     {
      "link": "http://www.southeasterndelivery.com/images/ProductImages/00051500240908.jpg"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
 ],
 "requestId": "0CLGzkcKVo64CFRDd5wod4mMAAA"
 }
```

I have the following code in my android app to parse it:

```java
try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray itemsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
    JSONObject productObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(0);
    //String productTitle = productObject.getString("title");
    //tv.setText(productTitle);
    tv.setText(productObject.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    tv.setText("JSONOBJECT Error: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
setContentView(tv);
```

The TextView on my Android app will now display (obviously not indented I did that for easy reading):

```
   "product": {
    "googleId": "9884865157760252836",
    "author": {
     "name": "Southeastern Delivery",
     "accountId": "7585088"
    },
    "creationTime": "2011-07-25T00:15:58.000Z",
    "modificationTime": "2012-02-11T09:29:00.000Z",
    "country": "US",
    "language": "en",
    "title": "Jif Peanut Butter, Creamy",
    "description": "Jif Creamy Peanut Butter. Fresh Roasted Peanut Taste. Look for the flavor seal. Contains no preservatives. No refrigeration required.",
    "link": "http://www.southeasterndelivery.com/Jif_Peanut_Butter_00051500240908/",
    "brand": "Jif Peanut Butter",
    "condition": "new",
    "gtin": "00051500240908",
    "gtins": [
     "00051500240908"
    ],
    "inventories": [
     {
      "channel": "online",
      "availability": "inStock",
      "price": 15.64,
      "shipping": 1.56,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ],
    "images": [
     {
      "link": "http://www.southeasterndelivery.com/images/ProductImages/00051500240908.jpg"
     }
    ]
   }
```

Now if you notice in my Java code I have two lines commented out. If I uncomment those lines and then comment the line:

```java
tv.setText(productObject.toString());
```

tv gets set to this error: "JSONOBJECT Error: org.json.JSONEception: No value for title". I am not sure why this is true because clearly their is a title in the productObject.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a level of information in your code. The JSON array contains *items*, which contains *products*, which have a *title*.

Your code should look like:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
JSONArray itemsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items"); 
JSONObject itemObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(0); 
JSONObject productObject = itemObject.getJSONObject("product");
String productTitle = productObject.getString("title");
```

Comment: Yup this is how I fixed my code. I figured this out shortly after I posted, but I could not answer my own question for 8 more hours because of my reputation. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [json-smart](http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/) in my project. It is very small and very fast. To convert your JSON from Sting to the actual object use `JSONObjet json = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(rawString);`

When you have JSONObject you treat it just like a Map. So `String title = (String) json.get("title")`

Comment: Thanks! This looks very helpful I will try implementing it!

I actually just solved my problem, but since I do not have 100 reputation I cannot post the answer for 8 more hours =\. When I can I will so everyone can see how to do it the way I was doing it, but yeah your way seems very practical! -Thanks!